# Creating which derived type of class at runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, derived-class

I've tried to understand some of the posts of similar, but don't quite understand their purposes and thought I'd explain my own...

I have a class -- fully defined with code with properties, and methods.  Many methods are virtual to be overriden by further derived class.  So, I have something like the following

```
Class_Main
  --  Class_A : Class_Main
  --  Class_B : Class_Main
  --  Class_C : Class_Main
  --  Class_D : Class_Main
```

I then need to define one more class that can be dynamically derived from A-D... such as:

```
Class_X : Class_A (or Class_B or Class_C or Class_D )
```

as I have additional properties and methods within the Class_X.  Since C# can't derive from two actual classes, but can use interfaces, but you can't have code in an interface, just abstract signatures, how might I go about doing such implementation.

Thanks

Comment: How do you intend instantiate objects using this paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds a bit like [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  This isn't available in C#, as it is a statically-typed language.  Perhaps when C# 4 comes around, [`dynamic`](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/10/27/c-dynamic.aspx) will give you what you are looking for.

If `Class_X` needs to be "filled in" with functionality from those classes, it would be common to pass that into the class at the time of instantiation:

```
public class Class_X {
    private Class_Main _impl;
    public Class_X(Class_Main impl) {
        _impl = impl;
    }
}

Class_X classXA = new Class_X(new Class_A());
Class_X classXB = new Class_X(new Class_B());
```

At this point, your `Class_X` instances have access to the `Class_Main` properties & methods for all derived classes.  This doesn't make `Class_X` an aggregate, just enables you to use the runtime behavior of any `Class_Main` from within `Class_X` (through the `_impl` object).

Comment: This was kind-of what I was thinking, but didn't know if there was another way... then my methods of class_X would do something like
return _impl.SomeFunction(whateverParam)  .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extend from one class and include the other class within Class X, and just have adapter methods to map directly to the class inside.

So, now exactly C#, just prototyping:

```
class ClassA {
  public void FunctionClassA(...) { ... }
  public void FunctionClassB(...) { ... }
}

class ClassX : ClassB {
  private ClassA classa;
  public ClassX() {
     classa = new ClassA();
  }
  public void FunctionClassA(...) { classa.FunctionClassA(...); }
}
```

So, ClassX now has one function inherited (by appearance) from ClassA, and contains all the methods of ClassB.